# Facebook app - how to share/like a page inside the app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

let's say I have the app as is shown in the tutorial in Facebook developer section: The Cookbook app which contains recipes.

If a user use this app and for example created a recipe, I want to give him a possibility to share (or "like") this recipe => which means, that onto his wall will be printed out the message like **User-ABC like Name_of_the_recipe** (or some equivalent for sharing this recipe).

How to do that?

Comment: u cant have a like functionality for a page which doesnt have a public site. within a canvas app you cnat have like functionality.

Comment: and something like "like" functionality? Any alternative? Because for the example I mentioned above it would be useful.

Comment: dude, u cant have `like` in a canvas app. u can have share.